# X11 Forwarding using Cygwin ssh got port 6000 Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, cygwin, portforwarding, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I try to forward X11 using Windows 10 machine as the client and a Ubuntu Linux machine as the server. The ssh is running under Cygwin, which contains xinit and xorg. The steps:

1. Turn on the linux server machine.
2. I enabled the forwarding both in the client and server side using sshd_config configuration file.
3. I set display in Cygwin by executing:
    export DISPLAY=r1:0.0
   where r1 is the name of the server
4. I enabled access list on the server side:
    xhost 192.168.1.143
5. Connect to the server from Cygwin using ssh.
6. Run lxterminal application, but got:

> ```
> r1@r1:~$ lxterminal    
> debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
> debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 37184
> connect r1 port 6000: Connection refused
> ```

Is r1 server port 6000 is rejecting? If yes, how so?

Answer (score 0):

From xorg-server-*1.17.4-1 cygwin announcement

https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-10/msg00111.html

> '-nolisten tcp' is now the default, so the server only accepts local
>   connections on a unix domain socket. A '-listen' option has been added
>   which can be used to restore the previous behaviour.

I guess the same is happening on the Linux server

Comment: hello, according to [link](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-remote-clients-cant-connect) , setting DISPLAY variable, enabling xhost, and using ssh -Y option is the solution for "nolisten tcp". I did that, but still got the problem

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I could not connect to port 6000 either.

What finally works is this hack:

```
sudo vi /usr/bin/Xorg
```

and add `-listen tcp` to the Xorg command(s):

```
#exec "$basedir"/Xorg.wrap "$@"
 exec "$basedir"/Xorg.wrap "$@" -listen tcp
```

Then save and exit the file and restart the user graphical interface:

```
 sudo service gdm restart
```

and then check that port 6000 is open:

```
 nmap localhost
```